# Colocar navbar na direita

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Como fazer para que o navbar fique na direita. Precisa ser esse modelo, pois já tem a logo, tem o menu e quando aberto em celular já aparece o menu mobile.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="imagens/logo.png" width="" height="30" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-left" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Isso pode ser a resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41513784/11650233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc pode colocar `d-flex` no `collaps` da `navbar` e alinhar os itens a esquerda com `justify-content-end` classes nativas do BS4, não precisa de CSS extra, consulte aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="imagens/logo.png" width="" height="30" alt="Logo">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-lg-flex justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      
        </div>
      </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Hugo. Deu certo.

Comment: Agora tenho que esperar 6 minutos, para marcar a resposta como concluído :(

Comment: @Tiago dessa vez eu fiu rápido no gatinho haha. Legal que resolveu ai, agradeço pela força 

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar a classe nativa `ml-auto` na `ul.navbar-nav`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="imagens/logo.png" width="" height="30" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-left" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```